# Facebook API - no email in response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is it possible to register Facebook account without having email tied to that account? I am asking because in *some* responses (1 out of 10000) I don't get email (I have perms="email" in request to API)?

Anyone have experience with this problem? What response do you display to user in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intermittent missing email address in facebook API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7603644/intermittent-missing-email-address-in-facebook-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`email` permission isn't one that blocks user from logging in, once granted it can be removed manually by user and he can avoid granting it in the future interactions with your app/site.

At least Facebook's JavaScript SDK passing user identity even if user skip granting `email` permission.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is possible, for the case user signed up via facebook mobile app on a phone, and registered using a phone number.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to register a facebook account without an email. If you have users connecting your application but you can't see their email address, they probably denied permission.

Comment: It is possible, via a phone number.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to have a facebook account without email, but it's possible to have it with unconfirmed email, in which case it's not provided via API:
[Facebook Email field return null (even if the “email” permission is set and accepted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532476/facebook-email-field-return-null-even-if-the-email-permission-is-set-and-acce)