# Facebook Connect API Email issue

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have some issue with the Facebook Connect API

I can't understand why for some users, I can't get the email field.

It working for some, and other not.

I did some debug to check the permissions :

```
$response = $facebook->api( "/me/permissions");
print_r($response, true);
```

and then I receive :

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [installed] => 1
                    [basic_info] => 1
                    [public_profile] => 1
                    [email] => 1
                    [user_friends] => 1
                )

        )
```

So the email permission is set but when I run:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

there is no email index in the array...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This might be the reason: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016/

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594547/21062 has an answer which is more specific to your case