# Returning email address from facebook javascript sdk login

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm playing around with the Facebook Javascript SDK to allow the end user to signup to my website via facebook, I've been following a tutorial online and so far so good, however I need to retrieve the user's email address, unfortunately response.email is always undefined, this is my code so far:

```
   FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    });
```

Which is executed off a button click, Now when I log response I have the userId and my name which is correct, after doing some googling some people have suggested I check that my email address on my facebook profile is set to public so I've gone through my profile set the relevant section to public but yet I still can't return the email address?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

I've gone through and asked for permissions via the facebook SDK outlining the email address, this is now the response back from facebook after logging in again:

[image]

Yet when I drill down into email I see this:

[image]

Not the actual email address?

Comment: I think you are using the public object that only contains first_name, last_name, gender etc.. but not email -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I've just added an update to my question, detailing where I am now with the issue.

Comment: I found a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532476/facebook-email-field-return-null-even-if-the-email-permission-is-set-and-acce check out if your email is confirmed and also you can use the username@facebook.com to send emails I think

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky: The `username@facebook.com` addresses are deprecated, Facebook will not put stuff send there in inbox any more, but only forward it to the user’s external email address. Plus, since API v2.0, you won’t _get_ the `username` any more.