# Getting email from Facebook - FB android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following code to get email and name of the user from facebook

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Display page
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(MainActivity.this);

    FBloginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    FBloginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Login the user through facebook when button is clicked
            onFblogin();
        }
    });

}

private void onFblogin() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // Set permissions
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_friends", "public_profile"));

    //Try logging in the user
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                    // Get facebook data from login
                    try {
                        email = object.getString("email");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        name = object.getString("name");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //new fbLogin().execute();

                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "email, name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
}
```

However, this only returns the name and not the email of the user. How can I get both?

Comment: there are many threads about this already, it can be a lot of things, just use the search function. (email not approved, token does not include the correct permission, ...)

Comment: object.optString("email");

Comment: @luschn The issue that I'm having now is that I'm getting the email when I click the login button the second time

Answer (score 3):

My working method like :

```
public void getUserDetailsFromFB(AccessToken accessToken) {

    GraphRequest req=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"graph request completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{
                String email =  object.getString("email");
                String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                String gender = object.getString("gender");
                String name = object.getString("name");
                String id = object.getString("id");
                String photourl =object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");

            }catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"graph request error : "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,birthday,picture.type(large)");
    req.setParameters(parameters);
    req.executeAsync();
}
```

Then in your LoginButton :

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            getUserDetailsFromFB(loginResult.getAccessToken());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fb user canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fb error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Init like :

```
LoginButton loginButton =(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                facebook:com_facebook_login_text="Fb login button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: I'm getting name, picture, id and gender but no email

Comment: Did you read this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532476/facebook-email-field-return-null-even-if-the-email-permission-is-set-and-acce

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I just realized that when I click the login button again the second time, I get the email address! Any idea why this is happening

Comment: Its the same still. Even if I use what you answered, I get the email when I click it the second time

Comment: and one more question : did you tried that process by using different facebook account

Comment: Yeah. Did it with two more. Same issue

Comment: Don't think thats an issue! I am getting the email on second try so the permissions are fine i think

Comment: can you post any logcat , on first click what you get which code blocks you get in and second click post logcat too with your final code.

Comment: I have got "No value for `birthday`" - why is that?