# Facebook PHP SDK v4 used with Facebook app v2.9 returns no email of the user, and more

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using Facebook JS SDK combined with **PHP SDK v4** to authenticate users via Facebook. The Facebook app I've been using is on version **2.3**.

Now, I needed to create a new FB app for another site - the current version of the newly created FB app is **2.9**. When I use the same code (using PHP SDK v4), suddenly, I am unable to get the authenticated user's email address, even though I still can do it when I switch to the old FB app. Also, the response from the 2.9 app has only 2 properties in it (id and full name), while the 2.3 one carries way more information.

I saw **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532476/facebook-email-field-return-null-even-if-the-email-permission-is-set-and-acce)**, however the user I'm trying to log in with:

- has granted all permissions to the Facebook app,
- registered with an email (not a phone number) on Facebook, and
- validated their email address.

---

**TL;DR**

Authenticating a user via Facebook app v2.3 returns their email address, but a new Facebook app of v2.9 - doesn't. PHP SDK version I use: 4.

---

Any idea what might have changed on Facebook side? Do I have to upgrade the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the v2.4, you have to specify the fields you're looking for in your request. And for all the different API calls, not only users.

> In the past, responses from Graph API calls returned a set of default
>   fields. In order to reduce payload size and improve latency on mobile
>   networks, we have reduced the number of default fields returned for
>   most Graph API calls. In v2.4 you will need to declaratively list the
>   response fields for your calls.

Tips: If you want to  have the list of all available fields, you need to do a query like this:

`$facebook->api('/me?metadata=1');`

And then you'll have to do something like this:

`$facebook->api('/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name');`

Comment: That, indeed, fixed my issue. You da man.